# Is "I think" unnecessary?

Tags: meaning

Is there *really* any difference between saying "X isn't funny" and saying "I didn't find X funny" or "I think X isn't funny"?

To address closing: When I say something isn't funny, people get upset.

Comment: There's no modal hedging in the first sentence. While such bald statements are usually not taken as necessarily totally or even partly true, using them is an arrogation, and can come across as judgemental.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I believe it is a much better fit on Interpersonal Skills.SE. It concerns modality (the pragmatics of speaker evaluation of a statement's truth value, and adding a caveat of subjectivity).

Comment: In your own language, isn't there a difference? Why wouldn't there be in English? I suggest you read about pragmatics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*X isn't funny* means that no-one would find it amusing, which isn't necessarily true - people's sense of humour varies. Also, people sometimes say "That isn't funny" to reproach others for laughing at a tasteless joke, or an accident that seems comical but that actually injured someone.

*I didn't find X funny* or *I don't think X is funny* describe your personal reaction to a joke or situation.

Comment: I see. Not funny means not approved but a personal reaction is not disapproval nor approval!?

Comment: No - I said that 'It 's not funny' _can_ be used to suggest that other people shouldn't find something funny. It can simply mean that something isn't at all amusing (perhaps it's boring or difficult to understand).

Comment: But it might explain why people get upset if I say it isn't funny